# monkeyrunner - ChimpException when trying to use view.getLocation()

Tags: android, jython, monkeyrunner

I've got a monkeyrunner script that is trying to get some information on one of the views, like so:

```
v = d.getViewById('id/search_progress_bar')
print dir(v)
for i in range(10):
    print 'about to call v.getLocation'
    print v.getLocation()
    m.sleep(1)
```

here's the output of the dir(v) step:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__str__', 'getAccessibilityIds', 'getChecked', 'getChildren', 'getEnabled', 'getFocused', 'getLocation', 'getParent', 'getSelected', 'getText', 'getViewClass', 'setFocused', 'setSelected']
```

however, when I try and use the v.getLocation() method, I get the exception below right away.

```
121024 16:30:26.373:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] Script terminated due to an exception
121024 16:30:26.373:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/swolfe/svn/jython/progress_bar_testing.py", line 20, in <module>
    print v.getLocation()
    at com.android.chimpchat.ChimpManager.queryView(ChimpManager.java:414)
    at com.android.chimpchat.core.ChimpView.queryView(ChimpView.java:52)
    at com.android.chimpchat.core.ChimpView.getLocation(ChimpView.java:64)
    at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyView.getLocation(MonkeyView.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

com.android.chimpchat.core.ChimpException: com.android.chimpchat.core.ChimpException: No accessibility event has occured yet
```

Is anybody familiar with ChimpChat? I undestand it's some of the core code for MonkeyRunner. What is the relationship between accessibility and MonkeyRunner, and why is it complaining that an accessibility event hasn't happened yet? Do I need to start some sort of accessibility or instrumentation service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. It doesn't work. However you can use [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient), which actually works, and the script would be:

```
vc = ViewClient(d, serialno)
v = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise('id/search_progress_bar')
print dir(v)
for i in range(10):
    print 'about to call v.getCoords'
    print v.getCoords()
    m.sleep(1)
```

and prints something like

```
['_View__dumpWindowsInformation', '_View__obtainPxPy', '_View__obtainStatusBarDimensionsIfVisible', '_View__obtainVwVh', '_View__obtainVxVy', '__call__', '__doc__', '__getattr__', '__getitem__', '__init__', '__module__', '__smallStr__', '__str__', '__tinyStr__', 'add', 'allPossibleNamesWithColon', 'build', 'children', 'currentFocus', 'device', 'factory', 'getCenter', 'getClass', 'getCoords', 'getHeight', 'getId', 'getParent', 'getPositionAndSize', 'getText', 'getUniqueId', 'getVisibility', 'getWidth', 'getX', 'getXY', 'getY', 'intersection', 'map', 'parent', 'touch', 'windows']
about to call v.getCoords
((0, 157), (480, 229))
about to call v.getCords
((0, 157), (480, 229))
...
```

which I doubt is your intention unless you are expecting your view to move.

Comment: thanks dtmilano, I am a big fan of your blog. When I saw the monkeydevice available methods, I thought maybe AndroidViewClient had been merged into MR. I'll definitely take a look at AVC, thanks!